# Correct multiple strings between two delimiters in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having trouble creating a batch file, which will correct some text files for me. So I need your advice.
I need to get the data in field |No=xxx| in numerical format without any alphabetic characters , special character or spaces

I'm looking for a Batch code that can do this work, because I have a lot of files with this problem.

The text files (input.txt) are made this way:

```
|Job=1|Typ=S|Action=Order|No=531.04220440.00|
|Job=1|Typ=P|Action=Information|M=1|
|Job=2|Typ=S|Action=Order|No=ALR-2005605 |
|Job=2|Typ=P|Action=Information|M=3|
….
|Job=99|Typ=S|Action=Order|No=AF502033H|
|Job=99|Typ=P|Action=Information|M=1|
```

I was not able to understand JREPL by the way.
I have to create files correting the input between |No=and |
The File Example should look like that ,after the batch (output.txt)

```
|Job=1|Typ=S|Action=Order|No=5310422044000|
|Job=1|Typ=P|Action=Information|M=1|
|Job=2|Typ=S|Action=Order|No=2005605|
|Job=2|Typ=P|Action=Information|M=3|
….
|Job=99|Typ=S|Action=Order|No=502033|
|Job=99|Typ=P|Action=Information|M=1|
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post some snippets of the approaches you have tried, so people can guide you to a solution.

Comment: You should search some key word firstly. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855925/removing-non-alphanumeric-characters-in-a-batch-variable) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465485/how-to-remove-alphabets-and-special-characters-from-a-string-using-regex-in-wind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36500938.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 ECHO "%%a"|FIND "|No=" >nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO(%%a
 ) ELSE (
  SET "line=%%a"
  CALL :process
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "tail="
:procloop
SET "line=%line:~0,-1%"
SET "char=%line:~-1%"
IF "%char%"=="=" (
 FOR %%x IN ("%line%%tail%|") DO ECHO(%%~x
 GOTO :EOF 
)
IF "%char%" geq "0" IF "%char%" leq "9" SET "tail=%char%%tail%"
GOTO procloop
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36500938.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

It would appear, though it is not explicitly stated, that you wish to eliminate all non-numerics between `|No=` and `|` at the end of each line.

The above simply detects whether the line contains `|No=` and assumes that if it appears, it is in the last field. If it does not appear, simply regurgitate the line. If it does appear, process the line in `line`.

The processing simply lops off the last character and then determines whether the new last-character is `=` or not. If it is, assume that it is the `=` in `No=`, so add back the tail and closing `|` and output that. By putting the required string in quotes, you can use `for` to assign it to `%%x` and then use `%%~x` to remove the enclosing quotes- otherwise you'll get awkward syntax error to resolve.

If the last character is not `=` but is `0`..`9` then accumulate it else ignore it and continue processing until `=` is detected.

Comment: It worked perfectly well on my first file, thank you @Magoo. Incredible , Thank you for your fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) solution

```
call jrepl "\D" "" /p "(\|No=)([\c|]+)(\|)$" /prepl "$1+{$2}+$3" /f input.txt /o output.txt
```